# Closed form of this integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

After putting values into Wolfram for the integral
$$\int_{2}^\infty \frac{x^k}{1 - x^{2k}} dx$$
And it seems that it can return the values.
If we have this, how might one go about solving 
$$\int_{2}^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}}{1 - x^{2k}} dx$$

Comment: It seems similar to the zeta integral.

Comment: Set $x^k=u$ in the last integral

Comment: Thank you so much. Lol I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k}{1-x^{2k}}\,dx = -\int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k}{x^{2k}-1}\,dx = -\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{y^{k-2}}{1-y^{2k}}\,dy $$
can be computed in explicit terms for any integer $k\geq 2$ by partial fraction decomposition, and it equals
$$ -\int_{0}^{1/2}\sum_{n\geq 0} y^{(2n+1)k-2}\,dy =-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{\left[(2n+1)k-1\right]2^{(2n+1)k-1}}$$
(which is a hypergeometric ${}_2 F_1$ function evaluated at $4^{-k}$) for any $k>1$.

The situation for $\int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x^{2k}}\,dx$ is *much* simpler: this is just $-\frac{1}{k}\text{arctanh}(2^{-k})$, for any $k>0$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It appears to be equivilent to $\frac{1}{k-1}\arctanh(\frac{1}{2^{k-1}})$